# Having problems with my ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax

I basically just copied this from the website for the ajax get shorthand. It keeps on saying $ is not defined.

```
 $.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats?order=-createdAt', function(data) {
   console.log(data) 
}
);
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: do you have jQuery loaded in your script files?

Comment: Is this cross-domain?

Comment: Try adding this to your inside the head tag: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sergio, I tried adding that into my head and it still does not work. It still says $ is not defined.

Comment: @user2562240 -- I'm assuming this isn't hosted on a web-server, try adding `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @user2562240 start by checking your console and network tab...

Comment: Please tell us how you are running your script - from a web server, or via WAMP/MAMP/etc ?

Answer (score 5):

Building on @Sergio's comment, you'd want something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats?order=-createdAt', function(data) {
        console.log(data) 
    });
</script>
```

HOWEVER, if you are loading this as a local file, your browser will NOT be able to load the jQuery libraries that way. This is because if you load a local file, the address bar will be something like `file:///<path to file>`.

When you load a script using `src="//<script` you are basically telling the browser "fill in whatever protocol I used when loading this page". So if you went to your page via `http://somesite`, then the browser would use "http:" as the protocol. However if you load a local file, the browser will use "file:" as the protocol, and thus will be trying to load jQuery as  `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` which of course is not going to work.

Why does the browser allow this? Well imagine you've coded this nice site that includes some files, but it includes them as http. But when you put that site live into production, you run it as https, since it needs to be secure. Most modern browsers will display an "insecure content" warning when they get try to load that script (since it's using http, and thus is not secure) and some will just silently fail to load it (and in cases like jQuery or other javascript libraries, this can cause whole segments of the page to not work). Leaving out the protocol allows the browser to decide what protocol to use based on what protocol the user requested for the overall page.

If this is the problem you're now facing (which I imagine it is, if you're loading the page this way), then this is the code you want:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But do be sure to change it back once you put this page into production.